# How can I get rid of a "MacShiny" icon from my menu bar?

Tags: menu-bar

Command and drag will not move it.
I've tried looking into library and user accounts but can't find the source. The MacShiny web site only tells how to uninstall the app itself, and says nothing about how to get rid of the icon.

Comment: Did you reboot yet?

Answer (score -1):

Down load app cleaner free and use it to get rid of this app. If you have already deleted Macshiny you will have to download it again and then use app clean